# Java Regex, replacing keyword in sql query

Tags: java, sql, regex, oracle

I'm trying to parse thousands of Oracle SQL script WHERE clauses.

I want to replace the keyword **user** (as in the person currently logged in) with something else. I can't just do a replace all as user may be used as part of another word in the where clause like a column name, for example, `payuser`. And I can't simply check is there whitespace on either side of it as it could be inside a bracket or have an equals sign next to it or some other mathematical character.

*where (username = **user** or admin = **user**) and loggedIn=**user**  order by pay_group_code;*

```
public class TestClass{

     public static void main(String []args){

        String where = "where (username = user or admin = user) and loggedIn=user  order by pay_group_code;";

        where = where.replaceAll("\buser\b", "test");

        System.out.println(where);
     }
}
```

Comment: can you provide a sample input and desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a `replaceAll`, you need to use double escape symbols:

```
where = where.replaceAll("(?i)\\buser\\b", "test");
```

Without the double escapes, you match a backspace BS symbol.

See [demo](https://ideone.com/s6MZYb)

Comment: Thanks, I'm also now using (?i) to ignore case so that the regex looks like "(?i)\\buser\\b".